# Поиск значения в JSON строке на plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Предположим есть строка в одной из ячеек таблицы:

```
{"value":"{\"result\":\"SUCCESS\",\"orderId\":1424,\"employerId\":2342}","description":null}
```

Есть ли способ без парсинга всей конструкции найти там значение по какому-либо адресу? Например:

```
declare
  my_str varchar2(200):='{"value":"{\"result\":\"SUCCESS\",\"orderId\":1424,\"employerId\":2342}","description":null}';
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(my_pkg.get_json_value(my_str, 'value;result'));
end;
```

И на выходе получить "SUCCESS".

Встретил только код на хабре, который строит временную таблицу по всей строке.

Версия 11.0.6.1796.

Comment: что-то с кавычками и экранированием перемудрили. SELECT json_value('{"value":{"result":"SUCCESS","orderId":1424,"employerId":2342}","description":"null"}', '$.value.result' RETURNING VARCHAR2(500)) FROM dual;

Comment: приведенный выше вариант работает с версии 12.1.0.2. не сразу обратил внимание на вашу версию.

Comment: А чем не устроило решение на хабре?

Comment: Тем, что слишком много действий ради проверки единственного значения. Сделал так, вроде работает (зато не работает форматирование кода в комментариях ._.):
`if v_order.execution_result is not null and v_order.execution_result <> 'null' then
          apex_json.parse (v_order.execution_result);
          apex_json.parse (apex_json.get_varchar2 ('value'));
          if (apex_json.get_varchar2 ('result')) <> 'SUCCESS' then v_fails_counter := v_fails_counter + 1; end if;`